# Why would a recently drafted player sign for less than slot value?

Tags: mlb, draft

Why would a recently drafted player sign for less than slot value?  This is their only chance to make some money before making the big club if that ever happens?  Seems to me it is not in the players best interest to sign for less money.

Comment: "it is not in the players best interest to sign for less money": Even when the alternative is to not sign at all?